# Set Multiple Selection Listview

Tags: c#, string, listview, uwp, multipleselection

I have a string `string a="A:B:D"`. Which means the selected listview is the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd index listview
I want to display multiple selection listview according to above string.
code:

```
string a="A:B:D"
string pattern = @"[^:]";
                                        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(a, pattern))
                                        {
                                            if (m.Value.Contains("A"))
                                            {
                                                ListManyOption.SelectedIndex = 0;
                                            }
                                            if (m.Value.Contains("B"))
                                            {
                                                ListManyOption.SelectedIndex = 1;
                                            }
                                            if (m.Value.Contains("C"))
                                            {
                                                ListManyOption.SelectedIndex = 2;
                                            }
                                            if (m.Value.Contains("D"))
                                            {
                                                ListManyOption.SelectedIndex = 3;
                                            }
```

But when I use the code above, only the 3rd index listview is selected.
How do I display the multiple selection listview according to the string above?

Comment: Is this a UWP project? Do you want to select the multiple listview items which match your string entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `SelectionMode` property of the `ListView` to `Extended` or `Multiple` and add the items to be selected to the `SelectedItems` collection:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(a, pattern))
{
    if (m.Value.Contains("A"))
    {
        ListManyOption.SelectedItems.Add(ListManyOption.Items[0]);
    }
    if (m.Value.Contains("B"))
    {
        ListManyOption.SelectedItems.Add(ListManyOption.Items[1]);
    }
    if (m.Value.Contains("C"))
    {
        ListManyOption.SelectedItems.Add(ListManyOption.Items[2]);
    }
    if (m.Value.Contains("D"))
    {
        ListManyOption.SelectedItems.Add(ListManyOption.Items[3]);
    }
}
```